# Numpy vectorize wrongly converts the output to be integer

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am struggling with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

e = np.linspace(0, 4, 10)

def g(x):
    if x > 1:
        return x
    else:
        return 0

vg = np.vectorize(g)

print(vg(e))
```

the result looks like this:

```
    [0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4]
```

I also checked the dtype. It seems that the vectorize function is conveting the type to int64 from float64!

Comment: When I change the 0 to 0.0, the problem is solved and I get float64. Is this correct behavior for vectorize to change the output to an int64 function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `np.vectorize` explains:

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
>   the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
>   by specifying the `otypes` argument.

The first element of your input is `0.0`, which returns the integer `0`, so as far as `numpy` knows, you want an integer dtype.  As you discovered, if you change this to `0.0` so you're not changing the return type, it'll behave.  Alternatively you can specify `otypes`:

```
>>> vg = np.vectorize(g)
>>> vg(e)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
>>> vg = np.vectorize(g, otypes=[np.float64])
>>> vg(e)
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.33333333,  1.77777778,
        2.22222222,  2.66666667,  3.11111111,  3.55555556,  4.        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

@amiragha

Python is looking at your input variables as ints as well, so if you wanted to keep everything float64 you would need to specify all necessary "numbers" as floats.